# Cassandra : node become unavailable, while ingesting with Spark

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

After few successfully ingested data into Cassandra with Spark,

an error is now returned every time I try to ingest data with Spark (after few minutes or instantly) :

`Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses`

I checked with simple CQLSH (not Spark), and similar error is indeed returned too (2 nodes of 4) :

`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'1.2.3.4': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('1.2.3.4', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

So basically, when I do ingestion into Cassandra with Spark, some nodes go down at some point. And I have to reboot the node, in order to access it again through cqlsh (and spark).

What is strange, is that it is still written "UP" for the given node when I run `nodetool status`, while `cqlsh` tells `connection refused` for that node.

I try to investigate logs, but I have a big problem : **nothing in the logs, no single exception triggered server-side**.

What to do in my case ? Why a node go down or become unresponsive in that case ? How to prevent it ?

Thanks

---

**!!! edit !!!**

---

Some of the details asked for, bellow :

**Cassandra infrastructure :**

- network : 10 gbps
- two datacenters : `datacenter1` and `datacenter2`
- 4 nodes in each datacenter
- 2 replicas per datacenter : 
  `CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '2', 'datacenter2': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;`
- consistency used for input and output : `LOCAL_QUORUM`
- total physical memory per node : 128GB.
- memory repartition per node : 64GB dedicated for each Cassandra instance, and 64GB dedicated for each Spark worker (colocated on each Cassandra node)
- storage : 4 TB NVME for each node

**Spark application config :**

- total executors cores : 24 cores (4 instances * 6 cores each)
- total executors ram : 48 GB (4 instances * 8 GB each)
- cassandra config on spark :

```
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows 1
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes 100
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key none
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.output.throughputMBPerSec 80
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level LOCAL_QUORUM
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.output.metrics false
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.connection.timeoutMS 90000
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra.spark.cassandra.query.retry.count 10
spark.sql.catalog.cassandra com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog
spark.sql.extensions com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions
```

Comment: how much resources are allocated for Cassandra. How much rows Spark is trying to write? Spark is basically overloads the Cassandra

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you for your reply. I have edited my post with full details asked. Any additionnal pointers ? How to determine the maximum troughput of my Cassandra cluster (in order to correctly configure spark) ? Which JMX indicators I need to care about to know if the cluster is overloaded or not ? (because the CPU for instance stuck at only 5% while ingesting..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (2 nodes of 4)

Just curious, but what is the replication factor (RF) of the keyspace, and what consistency level is being used for the write operation?

I'll echo Alex, and say that usually this happens because Spark is writing faster than Cassandra can process.  That leaves you with two options:

- Increase the size of the cluster to handle the write load.
- Throttle-back the write throughput of the Spark job.

One thing worth calling out:

> 2 replicas per datacenter

> consistency used for input and output : LOCAL_QUORUM

So you'll probably get more throughput by dropping the write consistency to `LOCAL_ONE`.

Remember, quorum == RF / 2 + 1, which means `LOCAL_QUORUM` of 2 *is* 2.

So I do recommend dropping to `LOCAL_ONE`, because right now Spark is effectively operating @ `ALL` consistency.

> Which JMX indicators I need to care about ?

Can't remember the exact name of it, but if you can find the metric for disk IOPs or throughput, I wonder if it's hitting a threshold and plateauing.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I added all the details you asked for, in my original post. Any additionnal pointers ? How to determine the maximum troughput of my Cassandra cluster in order to throttle back my spark job ? Which JMX indicators I need to care about ? As said to Alex, for example, my CPU are idle, even while ingesting.. so it is difficult to say that the cluster is overloaded just with this indicator

Comment: @Klun edit made!